# App on iOS device ignores changes in Xcode

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode

To explain the problem I give a short example. I create a new project in Swift language. Then I write only one line code for example in the viewDidLoad-method:

```
view.backgroundColor = .green
```

When I run the app on my iPhone6 device for the first time you see a green screen. As far as good. Then I change my code in

```
view.backgroundColor = .red
```

When I run it again instead of a red screen there is still the green screen. Any changes in my code are ignored (on a iOS simulator there is no problem!). I restarted Xcode again and also I did Cmd shift K but neither of them helped. I am grateful for any help.

(Xcode 11.0, iphone6 iOS 12.4.9, MacOS Majove 10.14.6)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense.

make sure that "view" is same with view that you seen.

example, add some label view.

hope your great job.

Comment: I used the view just as an example. Any kind of change in my code are ignored after running again. Even a change in a simple print statement are ignored!